# Use spread operator for function arguments

Tags: dart

So as of Dart 2.3 there is the option to use the Spread Operator for lists (...).

I was trying to use it for function arguments. Here is my specific use case:

```dart
String s = 'en_US';

Locale(...s.split('_'));             // here i get the error
```

I also tried:

```dart
Locale(...(s.split('_')));           // also error
```

Is there a way to make it work?
Because

```dart
Locale(s.split('_')[0], s.split('_')[1]);
```

doesn't really look nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't work. The spread operators *only* work in heterogenous sequences where it doesn't matter for program correctness how many elements it introduces. That means collection literals, but not argument lists.

The easiest approach is to just have a helper variable:

```dart
var splits = s.split('_');
... Locale(splits[0], splits[1]) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not valid dart syntax, you're likely thinking of JS.

If `Locale` is a function and you don't want to manually pass each argument you can use the `apply` function of the `Function` class. This allows you to dynamically call a function with the arguments passed as a `List`.

```dart
Function.apply(Locale, s.split('_'));
```

However, if it is a constructor, you would have to make a static factory constructor, which could then be passed to the `apply` function.

There are likely easier methods with reflection if that's available in your environment.